# Dynamically create datatable that allows population multiple times

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to dynamically create a datatable that will allow me to populate single records multiple times when a procedure is executed. I know how to create the datatable with the columns I need but my problem is that every time I execute the sub routine to add a record it re-initializes the datatable and wipes out the previously populated record. How do I create the datatable so that it initializes only once? I've tried initializing during the Page_Load event with a 'Not IsPostback' condition but that doesn't work. Any other ideas?

```
Partial Public Class ContactLookup
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Dim dtContacts As New DataTable

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        dtContacts = New DataTable
        dtContacts.Columns.Add("Email", GetType(String))
        dtContacts.Columns.Add("AccountNum", GetType(String))

    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub btnAddContact_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddContact.Click

    Dim AcctNum As String = txtLocAcct.Text
    Dim Email As String = txtEmail.Text
    Dim drContacts As DataRow = dtContacts.NewRow

    drContacts("Email") = Email
    drContacts("AccountNum") = AcctNum
    dtContacts.Rows.Add(drContacts)

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Let your method take a `DataTable` as input. Then this is used and returned. Apart from that, show your code.

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct than you need the table returned by the query as datatable. If its so then you can try this. Change your SqlCommand like this,

```
var dt =new DataTable(); // a new table to populate dynamically.

var reader = cmd.ExecuterReader(CommandBehaviour.SequentialAccess");

dt.Load(reader);

return dt; // now your dt will be query dependent.
```

Sorry the answer is in C#. You can convert it to VB at http://converter.telerik.com

**Updated Answer**

In your case i would suggest create a class instead of datatables and datacolumns. See a sample below:

```
public class Student
{
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public int Roll{get;set;}
}
```

In your code behind

```
private Student _stud = new Student();
private void FillObjects(){
  _stud.Name= txtName.Text;
 _stud.Roll=Convert.ToInt32(txtRoll.Text);
}

private void ButtonClick{
 FillObjects();
 YourClass.SaveMethod(_stud);
}
```

Comment: I'm populating the datatable from textbox inputs

Comment: see my updated answer. I am posting from mobile so it might loose formatting